# How to match any uppercase letter followed by the corresponding lower case letter?

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement that says a name must not start with 3 identical letters ignoring their case. A name starts with an upper case letter followed by lower case letters.

Basically I could convert the whole name to upper case and then match with a regex like `(\p{Lu})\1{3,}.*`.

But I was wondering if there exists a regex that matches the above requirements and does not need any preprocessing of the string to be matched. So what regex can I use to match strings like `Aa`, `Dd` or `Uu` without explicitly specifiying any possible combination?

**EDIT:**
I accepted Markos answer. I just needed to fix it to work with names of length 1 and two and anchor it at the beginning. So the actual regex for my use case is `^(\p{Lu})(\p{Ll}?$|(?=\p{Ll}{2})(?i)(?!(\1){2}))`.

I also upvoted the answers of Evgeniy and sp00m for helping me to learn a lesson in regexes.

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: `(?i)(\p{Lu})\1{2,}.*` will not do, but wanted to point out 2, as one letter already matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit to rising on the shoulders of giants (the other posters here), but this solution actually works for your use case:

```
final String[] strings = { "Aba", "ABa", "aba", "aBa", "Aaa", "Aab" }; 
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Lu})(?=\\p{Ll}{2})(?i)(?!(\\1){2})");
for (String s : strings) System.out.println(s + ": " + p.matcher(s).find());
```

Now we have:

1. a match for one upcase char at front;
2. a lookahead assertion of two lowcase chars following;
3. another lookahead that asserts these two chars are not both the same (ignoring case) as the first one.

Output:

```
Aba: true
ABa: false
aba: false
aBa: false
Aaa: false
Aab: true
```

Comment: +1 This should meet all requested requirements (when a `.*` is added to the end) (I haven't read the question properly), I will not change my solution now, since yours is very similar to what I found now.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    String regex = "(?i)(.)(?=\\p{javaLowerCase})(?<=\\p{javaUpperCase})\\1";
    System.out.println("dD".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("dd".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("DD".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("Dd".matches(regex));
```

output

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: Looks promising. Also also fails to match strings like `Dc`.

Answer (score 2):

This matches any uppercased letter followed by the same letter, uppercased or not:

```
([A-Z])(?i)\1
```

This matches any uppercased letter followed by the same letter, but necessarily lowercased:

```
([A-Z])(?!\1)(?i)\1
```

For example in Java,

```java
String pattern = "([A-Z])(?!\\1)(?i)\\1";
System.out.println("AA".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("aa".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("aA".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("Aa".matches(pattern));
```

Prints

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: Thanks for this short one. I also tried and it didn't match `AA`. Also fails to match `Ab`.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker So I didn't really get you question... It answers *"what regex can I use to match strings like `Aa`, `Dd` or `Uu` without explicitly specifiying any possible combination"*. But you need to match `AA` and `Ab` too?

Comment: The regex must not match `AA`. Your answer is correct as far as I have tested.

Answer (score 2):

Evgeniy Dorofeev solution is working (+1), but it can be done simpler, using only a lookahead

```
(\\p{Lu})(?=\\p{Ll})(?i)\\1
```

`(\\p{Lu})` matches a uppercase character and stores it to `\\1`

`(?=\\p{Ll})` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) ensuring that the next character is a lowercase letter.

`(?i)` is an inline modifier, enabling case independent matching.

`\\1` matches the uppercase letter from the first part (but now case independent because of the modifier in front).

Test it:

```
String[] TestInput = { "foobar", "Aal", "TTest" };

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Lu})(?=\\p{Ll})(?i)\\1");

for (String t : TestInput) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(t + " ==> " + true);
    } else {
        System.out.println(t + " ==> " + false);
    }
}
```

Output:

> foobar ==> false
>   Aal ==> true
>   TTest ==> false

Comment: This involves only the first two chars (should be three). Also, it doesn't seem to achieve the requirement even for the first two chars: it should give true for "Ab" and false for "AB", "ab", "aB", and "Aa". But still, +1 from me for good techniques, I think it can be fixed.

Comment: @stema +1 now I know about \\p{Ll}

Answer (score 1):

> I have a requirement that says a name must not start with 3 identical letters ignoring their case.

You should use the case-insensitive option: `(?i)`

and the "catch-all" `\w` e.g.: `(?i)(\w)\1{2,}.*`

or just `[a-z]` e.g.: `(?i)([a-z])\1{2,}.*`

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense here to use separate checks for the different requirements, especially since requirement lists tend to grow over time.

Your requirements as described are:

> A name must not start with 3 identical letters ignoring their case

and

> A name starts with an upper case letter followed by lower case letters.

Performing a separate check for each (as described in the other posts) also allows you to give the user proper error messages describing what is actually wrong. And it's certainly more readable.